# Есть проблема в понимании задания по двумерным массивом php

Tags: php

Задание:

- функцию `mySortForKey($a, $b)`. `$a` – двумерный массив вида `[['a'=>2,'b'=>1],['a'=>1,'b'=>3]]`, `$b` – ключ вложенного массива. Результат ее выполнения: двумерном массива `$a` отсортированный по возрастанию значений для ключа `$b`. В случае отсутствия ключа `$b` в одном из вложенных массивов, выбросить ошибку класса `Exception` с индексом неправильного массива.

Не понимаю как мы можем передать в функцию `$b` (ключ вложенного массива), и как `$b` может быть тогда в одном из вложенных массивов. В общем, хотелось бы узнать расшифровку этого задания, я пока что начинающий и много не понимаю. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Скидывать готовый код не нужно, просто немного объяснить.

Comment: Вот так `mySortForKey([['a'=>2,'b'=>1],['a'=>1,'b'=>3]], 'b')`

Comment: понял, а что нужно отсортировать?

Comment: Массив `$a`, переданный первым аргументом.

Comment: извините конечно, но что значит отсортированный по возрастанию значений для ключа $b?)

Answer (score 1):

В задании просят написать функцию, которая будет сортировать вложенные массивы массива `$a` по ключу `$b`, то есть **по значению ключа `$b`** по возрастанию.

Таким образом, функция должна выдавать такие результаты:

```
// Вызов
mySortForKey(
    [
        ['a'=>2,'b'=>3],
        ['a'=>8,'b'=>7],
        ['a'=>4,'b'=>1],
    ], 
    'b' 
);
// Результат
// значение ключа `'b'` в каждом следующем элементе 
// (подмассиве) больше или равно чем в предыдущем
[
    ['a'=>4,'b'=>1],   // b = 1
    ['a'=>2,'b'=>3],   // b = 3, больше чем 1
    ['a'=>8,'b'=>7],   // b = 7, больше чем 3
]
```

Comment: спасибо, уже написал